# I get a "cannot set a static reference error" how do i set the view to an xml file

Tags: java, android, xml

So im trying to go to an XML file called "youfailed" and for some reason i am getting an error saying that it cannot get a static reference. Is there any way to do what im trying to do?

```
public class DrawingView extends View {



    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }
    RectF rectf = new RectF(0, 0, 200, 0);

    private static final int w = 100;
    public static int lastColor = Color.BLACK;
    private final Random random = new Random();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final int radius = 230;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    public static int redColor = Color.RED;
    public static int greenColor = Color.GREEN;
    int randomWidth = 0;
    int randomHeight = 0;
    public static int addPoints = 0;



    private final Runnable updateCircle = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            lastColor = random.nextInt(2) == 1 ? redColor : greenColor;
            paint.setColor(lastColor);
            invalidate();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);

        }
    };



    @Override 
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        handler.post(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        handler.removeCallbacks(updateCircle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        // your other stuff here
        if(random == null){
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }else {
            randomWidth =(int) (random.nextInt(Math.abs(getWidth()-radius/2)) + radius/2f);
            randomHeight = (random.nextInt((int)Math.abs((getHeight()-radius/2 + radius/2f))));
        }

        canvas.drawCircle(randomWidth, randomHeight + radius/2f, radius, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
   int x = (int) event.getX();
   int y = (int) event.getY();
   if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
      //Do your things here
       if(redColor == lastColor){
           Activity.setContentView(R.layout.youfailed);
       } else {
           addPoints++;
       }
   }else {

   }
   return true;
}

private boolean isInsideCircle(int x, int y){
  if ((((x - randomWidth)*(x - randomWidth)) + ((y - randomHeight)*(y - randomHeight))) < ((radius)*(radius)))
    return true;
  return false;    
}




}
```

The error shows up in this method

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       int x = (int) event.getX();
       int y = (int) event.getY();
       if(isInsideCircle(x, y) ==  true){
          //Do your things here
           if(redColor == lastColor){
               //it shows up right below here
               Activity.setContentView(R.layout.youfailed);
           } else {
               addPoints++;
           }
       }else {

       }
       return true;
    }
```

Comment: A way to do what you're trying but would be blasphemous and a glaring example of not understanding a lot about a lot would be to override the `DrawingView` constructor to take a parameter of `Activity` then instead do `thePassedActivity.setContentView(...);`

Comment: It escapes me why you would give such an advice, when you already say that it's bad to begin with...

Comment: Thats the incorrect way to use "blasphemous" lol, but i tried both your ways and i couldn't find a solution. I could update my question to show you how it looks

Comment: @DevinTripp, I beg your pardon sir - it is you that doesn't understand the various ways in which blasphemous can be used. In this case it is blasphemous because to do what I've said would break what is held sacred by those "in-the-know". Look it up - the internet is amazing!

Comment: @Mjoellnir, if you care to address someone directly @ them as I did you. Since you asked, it's because of duplicate [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29404973/how-to-extend-two-classes-so-that-i-may-set-a-new-activity-in-view), which you may find [common](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4709389/devin-tripp?tab=questions&sort=newest). So what I'm getting here is they're not as concerned with doing it *right* as they are with getting it done. I'm not here to police the programming world.

Comment: Oh, I'm not sure what "both" ways you're talking about; I only stated one. Either way I wouldn't update this code cause it might make the post unclear. Since that, despite my warnings, see @Mjoellnir, you're willing to do it - figure out for yourself how you could do something like `DrawingView dv = new DrawingView(context, theActivityYouNeedToUse);` Then pass the activity where you're trying to set the view into the other view. *Again...."BAAAAAD!!"*

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
Activity.setContentView(R.layout.youfailed);
```

it doesn't work this way.
You need an actual activity to set the content view. setContentView is not a static method.

UPDATE:

You seem to try to change the content of an Activity from within one of it's Child-View objects, which is very bad style and should not be done.

A View should never have control over what it's parent actually displays.
However, a callback into the parent could solve your issue.

A callback is simply an interface with one or more methods, in your case one: "onFailure()", and it would be implemented by e.g. the Activity. This "onFailure()" is called in your onTouch() instead of the setContentView(), and within your actual Activity's implementation (which has to register itself as a callback receiver just like you do with onClickListeners or onTouchListeners), you can do whatever you like.

Example for a Callback-Interface:

```
public interface FailureCallback {
  public void onFailure();
}
```

You can put that as an internal interface into your DrawingView class. In your DrawingView class, you'll need a setter for the actual callback-instance and then you can call from within the onTouch() method.

In your implementation of the callback, you should not change the content of the running activity, btw - instead consider calling a new Activity using startActivity(...).

Comment: what do i need to do in order to fix this. Whats the solution?

Comment: No, you need a reference to an actual instance of the Activity class when you want to call an instance-method like setContentView(). But in your case, you'd probably want a callback that delegates the call to a fragment or activity. Or may be consider showing a toast or dialog...A View is not the right place to change an Activity's content. Very bad style.

Comment: so i need to make a method called onFailur() in my .Main class then i need to call it in the onTouch method like so Main.onFailure(); and in that onFailure method i will set the content view to youfailed

Comment: See my updated answer, it should provide enough information, now.

Comment: Constant practice, honing and improving of skills, reading books and learning from mistakes. Asking questions, learning from the answers. How does one get good at anything? :)

Comment: i practice every day until about 5am and i still feel almost as lost as i was in the begging. Just as i start to get something basic something advanced comes up in that basic concept and changes my whole idea on the subject. How did you get your start in programming. What books did you read?

Comment: and how do i make the setter

Comment: "setter for the actual callback instance"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74296/discussion-between-mjoellnir-and-devin-tripp).

Comment: and what is an interface

Comment: ive gotten this far simply through trial and error. I never really understand what im doing. i mean i kinda do im just not at like the "ohhhhhhhh" stage of figuring it out.